# Calling .Net framework Service Fabric Actor from .Net Core Stateless Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless, service-fabric-actor

The actor has a dependency on a Nuget package that is written in .Net Framework. 
The interfaces project is written in .Net standard, so it can be consumed from .Net core stateless service.

When I try to call my actor from stateless service, I am getting an error:

```
FabricInvalidAddressException: NamedEndpoint 'V2Listener' not found in the address '{"Endpoints":{"":"abc.mydomain.com:30001+7cd01089-ada5-47b4-b057-c5ec048e5c9e-131856623077216555-c8ffdd2b-d8de-4fb1-a0c4-6aa54aede1a4"}}' for partition '7cd01089-ada5-47b4-b057-c5ec048e5c9e'
Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientFactoryBase<TCommunicationClient>.CreateClientWithRetriesAsync(ResolvedServicePartition previousRsp, TargetReplicaSelector targetReplicaSelector, string listenerName, OperationRetrySettings retrySettings, bool doInitialResolve, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I've tried looking into adding V2Listener on the actor by following listener upgrade tutorial from microsoft, but no success.

Comment: Did you add a service endpoint named `ServiceEndpointV2` in the service manifest of your actorservice? And are you using `FabricTransportActorRemotingProviderAttribute`?

Comment: This was the issue, thank you. I was using FabricTransportServiceRemotingProviderAttribute instead of Actor attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that:

1. You are using `FabricTransportActorRemotingProviderAttribute` on your actor service.
2. You have a service endpoint named 'ServiceEndpointV2' in the service manifest of your actorservice